# all inputs of a certain class to json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this type of html:

```
<input id='a1' name='a1' value='111' class='hey'/>
<input id='b1' name='b1' value='222' class='hey'/>
<input id='c1' name='b1' value='333' class='hey'/>
```

and I need to obtain this json from it:

```
{ a1: '111', b1: '222', c1: '333' }
```

anybody knows how ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serialize form to JSON with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should be pretty easy:

```
var json = {};
$('input.hey').each(function() {
  json[this.name] = this.value;
});
```

There are serialization routines supplied by jQuery to (for example) vaccuum up a whole form, but in a case like this it's pretty easy to just roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

```
var json = {};

$('input.hey').each(function(index) {
  json[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});
```